Performance catamaran
I was looking at You Tube build videos of small performance catamarans
Most of the builders chose both the sides of the catamaran to have a  triangular profile shape like this one here:

On the other hand, I know performance boats usually prefer hulls to be as thin as possible and to have a low center of gravity.
So wouldn't it be better to use this shape of hulls (almost straight and thin)

In other words, what would be better to reduce drag, deeper beam line but thinner profile? or the other way around?

you still need buoyancy to keep the thing afloat, that needs volume

You are right the beam waterline would be deeper, and that sounds to me like a good thing because the CG will be also lower. wouldnt it?

larger water contact area would result in greater friction

it isn't that simple, there are trade-offs between displacement depth, hull shape, and hull length

For small cat's, beaching is a factor. The V shape reduces contact with the ground, and how much to be reinforced for that purpose. The next factor is that small catamarans can be sailed at high speed, in daring fashion (ie crew on trapeze - fun and terrifying!), on just one of the hulls. This is the configuration that matters for high speed. With enough heel, you could have a semi planing situation. Also there's banana curvature eg on the classic Hobie 16. But that one's unique. Lastly, being able to take occasional waves head-on without pitchpoling. A sharp bow shape might help there, dunno

Depends entirely on the design speed of the boat, and the sea state you are expecting to operate in. The optimum in smooth water below 'hull speed' is semicircular, but that is not very fast for 16' boats (5 knots ish). The book you need is  High Speed Sailing: Design Factors (A Study of High-Performance Multihull Yacht Design) by Norwood.
The resistance of a displacement hull is composed of two main parts, skin friction and wave forming drag. The former dominates at low speed, until the effective hull length (an ambiguous concept) approaches half the wavelength of the wave being formed, where the bow is effectively trying to climb over the peak of the wave being  formed. Friction is still important after the boat speed exceeds this speed, in fact on plots of resistance vs speed it is not always obvious when so called hull speed (and its multiples) are reached.
For instance in deep water it is not entirely obvious where wave making drag kicks in for HMS Cossack, a slender hulled destroyer with a nominal hull speed of 22 knots.

Your second photo has excessive wetted area and so will have a lot of friction. It'll also be very tippy because dropping one hull by a bit doesn't increase the volume displaced very much.
As it turns out the actual optimal cross sectional form of a non lifting slender catamaran hull is semi circular even above hull speed, simply because the mechanism that generates wave forming drag doesn't much care about hull cross section shape at any particular station along the hull, and friction is always minimised by a semi circular shape (max buoyancy/surface area). Here's a rough comparison between a semi circular hull and a much simpler to construct trapezoidal hull. The trapezoidal hull has a significant advantage when the boat starts to plane - the flat bottom is much better suited to planing than the semicircular one. That's because of the different physics between a planing hull and a displacement one.

Lifting hulls such as conventional planing, stepped and hydrofoil hulls are way beyond what I can put in a little text box - Savitsky is the key word there for planing hulls and the like.

Thankyou for your answer, Ill look for that book to read. can you please add a picture of the semi circular hull shape you wrote about? also wouldnt the friction created by the wetted area of the second cat be far lesser then the drag created by the front cross section at low speed (you litteraly have to push water out of the way rather then the friction of the water on the side of the hull)?

Yes you still need a fine entry and a properly designed stern, you can't just cut it off square- well you can sort of at the stern.
